# Instertar datos en MySQL con pyMySQL

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de insertar datos en una tabla de una base de datos, sin embargo, a la hora de ejecutar el codigo no manda ningun error, pero en la tabla tampoco me aparece ningun nuevo registro. Adjunto codigo:

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host='Aqui mi Host (es remota)', 
            user='mi usuario',
            password='mi password',
            db='nombre de la base de datos'
            )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        print ("Conexion exitosa")
    def save_data(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, typeuser, area, passworduser) VALUES ('prueba', 'prueba','prueba', 'prueba')"

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            #user = self.cursor.fetchone()
            #print (user)
        except Exception as e:
            raise   
database = DataBase()
database.save_data()
```

Si pruebo este SQL en la consola, funciona correctamente. Incluso, lo tengo programado tambien en PHP y la instruccion funciona sin problemas. Pero en Python, no hace absolutamente nada. Repito, no me da ningun error por consola.

Version de Python: 3.10.3
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

No da error porque el código está correcto, pero incompleto.
PyMysql trabaja con transacciones, así que debes hacer `commit` para guardar los cambios en la BD. Ver [documentación](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/). Así que para arreglarlo solo tienes que agregar la línea después de `execute()`:

```
self.connection.commit()
```

Por otro lado, la forma correcta debe ser con consultas preparadas y no hacer reemplazos directos en la consulta SQL, eso dificulta las [inyecciones SQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=inyeccion+sql).

```
    def save_data(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, typeuser, area, passworduser) \
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql, ('prueba', 'prueba', 'prueba', 'prueba'))
        except Exception as e:
            self.connection.rollback()
            self.connection.close()
            raise
        else:
            self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.close()
```

Otra opción es agregar en `self.connection()` esto: `autocommit=True`